# Jsrender template form validation

Tags: validation, jsrender

I have a form which is a jsrender template

```
 <script id="editTemplate" type="text/x-jsrender">
 <div>
  <form id="myEditForm"  method="POST" action="">
  <table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      Id:
     </td>
     <td>
    <input type="text" name="id" value="{{>id}}" class="required" />
     </td>
     </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
      Name:
    </td>
    <td>  
    <input type="text" name="name" value="{{>name}}" class="required" />
    </td>
   </tr>
    <td>    
   <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </td>
   </tr>    
  </form>
```

I tried to add bassistance plugin based validation to the input fields but as the form is a jsrender template it is not working. any idea how to implement it???

Comment: Since you're only templating the table within the form (which seems to be missing a `</table>` tag, btw) could you have the form on the page and then just fill it in with the template? Then you might be able to more easily attach a plugin to the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was i was adding the validation logic in the  section of the html page where i created the form.

Validations could only be applied to the form once the template was compiled which happened in a seperate js file so, i added the validation code after the jsrender template was compiled ie., after these line in the js file

```
    var html = $.render["edit-tmpl"](rowData); // adding row data to edit-tmpl

var edtdlg = $("#editDialog").html(html); // adding the template to
                                                                                      // editDialog
```

and now it works like charm:)